# How to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{S_n}{n^{1-\alpha}}\right) = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $-\infty<\alpha<1 $ and $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{k^\alpha}\right)$

How to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{S_n}{n^{1-\alpha}}\right) = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}$

Would really appreciate your input :)

Comment: It would help the question to know what you have already tried or where you're having trouble.

Comment: I didn't really succeed to do anything, and it took me a long time to write this post, since I don't know LaTeX...

Comment: Try using Riemann sum